# Controlling the relative height of divs in relation to its neighbor with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a layout where I have three divs on a page. Image below is a rough diagram of the layout as it currently sits. My question is how would I scale one div to match the height of two stacked divs next to it on a page?

I'm working with bootstrap.

[The div to the right, would be the div that would scale to the total height of the two divs to the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmSOj.jpg)

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of what you have so far, preferably in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/9029328).

Answer (score 0):

Your tags say you're using Bootstrap 4. I would suggest that you start by nesting cols and optionally using flex-based classes to style things up where needed:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 sidebar">
            <p>Sidebar</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 content">
                    <p>Content</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 content">
                    <p>More content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen of the above](https://codepen.io/danbrazier/pen/vdVaZM).